# Deep linking in docusaurus generates 404 page not found errors

Tags: github-pages, docusaurus

[ampersandtarski.github.io](https://ampersandtarski.github.io/) is a site generated with [docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/docs) and hosted by [github pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages). Currently, during generation docusaurus doesn't detect any broken links. Also, the links at the site work as expected, as long as you use the links from the site themselve.

The weird thing is, that whenever you copy a link and open it in a new tab of your browser, it returs a 404-page-not-found error. Therefor deep linking to specific pages on the site doesn't work as well.

I am amazed by this phenomenon, and I am clueless to where to look for a (direction to a) solution.
Does anybody have an idea on what may cause this undesired effect?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: If I generate the docusaurus site locally, by cloning the repository at https://github.com/AmpersandTarski/AmpersandTarski.github.io , go to that directory and build it using `docker compose up -d --build`, I get the generated site at localhost, where all links are fine, and also opening such links in another tab works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I figured out what was going wrong. It had to do with the casing. A directory where most of the docs were stored, started with an upper-case character. After changing this all to lowercase, my problem was solved.